# tclreadline - insert-completions

Tags: c, tcl, readline

I'm using tclreadline to handle completions in my project, which is written in C/C++ and TCL.
I had to modify some configurations to deal with Readline 6.2, but I managed it.

I have 3 problems:

1. I defined other commands in the TCL interpreter, like `get_ports` and `get_modules`.

   If I type `get_por`, it correctly executes `get_ports`, but the history says `get_por`.

   If I type `get_por -of_objects [get_mod]`, it correctly executes `get_ports -of_objects [get_modules]`, but the history says `get_por -of_objects [get_mod]`. So the command is not expanded before adding it to the history. How can I manage this?
2. If I type `get_por -of [get_mod]` it doesn't expand `-of` in `-of_objects`, because I check for `-of_objects` inside the command and it doesn't appear. How can I manage `INSERT-COMPLETIONS` mode of readline? Or alternatively, any kind of `INSERT-ALL-COMPLETIONS` ?
3. If I type `get_por -of`<kbd>TAB</kbd>, tclreadline issues an error of `ScriptCompleter`, which says that `get_por` is not a command. It should complete the command, first, and then complete the option, which is defined in a `proc complete(get_ports)`.

Comment: I've done next to nothing with tclreadline, and I'd be genuinely interested in the answers to this…